# Reading text file in C++ and output formatting

Tags: c++, text-files

I read a text file in C++ using this code:

```
void main()
{
    clrscr();
    ifstream o("file.txt",ios::in);
    while(!o.eof())
    {
        o.get(w);
        cout<<w;
    }
    getch(); 
}
```

but output shows empty spaces between individual letters in the file,
although there are no such spaces in the original file.
Example: If file has `hello`, my output shows `h e l l o`.

How to rectify?

Comment: How is `w` defined?

Comment: Also `void main` is wrong. It should be `int main` to be standard compatible

Comment: it is char w; sorry i forgot to mention it

Comment: If the file contains wchar_t then use wcout to print contents.

Comment: Is the file using UTF-16 by chance? In that case it might be that `char` is 8bit on your compiler (most common size) and that it reads the "second" part of each character (which should be 00) and prints that out as a white space?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
while (o>>w) cout<<w;
```

And since you re dealing with unicode, char wont work out. Try using 
wchar_t.